# How to use an image more than one place in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am designing a background for my page which will include air bubbles. I would like to put one bubble image into a lot of places on the screen. I use the following code in my HTML file:

```
<body>
<div class="bg">
       <img id="bubble" src="images/bubble.png" />
</div>
```

Is there a way to put this bubble image into several places?

If you can direct me to another post (I couldn't find any) or give me a solution I will appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Note: Using a single background file with bubbles already in place is not an option.

Comment: You could use javascript, but thats not the best solution for anything very important.

Comment: Define "several places"?  Are they designated places?  Background images?  Constant pattern or random?  I guess what Im asking is what's the general intention of your query?

Comment: They will not be arranged randomly, I will define the margins/positions manually myself. They won't have a repeating pattern too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a CSS style that defines a [background-image](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp) for the bubble and apply the style to any page element you want to have a bubble. Also define styles to help [position](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp) the elements.

```
.bubble {
  background-image:url('images/bubble.png');
}

.top {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.bottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

<body>
<div class="bubble top">
       
</div>
<div class="bubble bottom">

<div>
</body>
```

There are several other background properties to help you get the affect you want; position, repeat, size, clip.

Comment: This is a little more efficient I than the other ones, I will use this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can add a CSS class

```
.bg {
    background: transparent url(images/bubble.png) no-repeat;
}
```

Then reuse the class are required

Comment: So is there no better way? I was looking for a more efficient way but I guess I will end up using this :/

Answer (score 0):

you will need a container that will hold your bubble

```
<div id="bubble1" class="bubbles"></div>
<div id="bubble2" class="bubbles"></div>
<div id="bubble3" class="bubbles"></div>
```

then in your .css

```
.bubbles{ 
  background: url(images/bubble.png);
  position: absolute;}

#bubble1{
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}
#bubble2{
  left: 50px;
  top: 150px;
}
#bubble3{
  left: 80px;
  top: 180px;
}
```